# Python Pandas - How convert sort_values output into dictionary using to_dict()

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Here is my code

```
from pandas import *
from collections import OrderedDict

def STC_define(stc_file, sheet):
    stc = stc_file
    stc_sheetname = sheet
    stc_xlsx = ExcelFile(stc)
    stc_df = stc_xlsx.parse(stc_sheetname, convert_float=True)
    stc_dic = stc_df.to_dict()
    return stc_df

stc_file = 'test1.xlsx'
sheet = 'Sheet1'
df = STC_define(stc_file, sheet)
print df
```

output **

```
   Floor  Room  Code
0     G     2    A567
1     K    10    A567
2     F     5    A567
3     D     8    A555
4     B     8    A555
5     H     3    A567
```

I get the correct output when I sort using sort_values. What I want to do now is convert the sorted value into a dictionary using to_dict().

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Floor'])
dic = df.to_dict()
print df
print dic
```

output**

```
   Floor  Room  Code
4     B     8  A555
3     D     8  A555
2     F     5  A567
0     G     2  A567
5     H     3  A567
1     K    10  A567

{u'Code': {0L: u'A567', 1L: u'A567', 2L: u'A567', 3L: u'A555', 4L: u'A555', 5L: u'A567'}, u'Room': {0L: 2L, 1L: 10L, 2L: 5L, 3L: 8L, 4L: 8L, 5L: 3L}, u'Floor': {0L: u'G', 1L: u'K', 2L: u'F', 3L: u'D', 4L: u'B', 5L: u'H'}}
```

Is there a way for order to say sorted converting to the dictionary using to_dict() or is there another way I can convert the dataframe into a dictionary? I would like the dictionary format to stay the same also

Answer (score 1):

## No, you can't order a Python dictionary.

[Python dictionaries are unordered:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary). A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way dictionaries are written on output.